# T-SQL : develop date ranges or date sequences from an existing table and input parameters, WITHOUT using DB objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, date-range

I have a scenario in SQL Server 2016, using T-SQL language.

I have a source table, as below:

[image]

While the date range for ABC and HDF are incomplete in the month (of April), the range for PQR is the full month (perfectly complete), and that for RST is complete with 2 sequences (without any break in the month).

I have two parameters to pass for this table, both date values (usually the beginning and the end of a month).

```
DECLARE @RangeStart AS date = '2021-04-01'
DECLARE @RangeEnd AS date = '2021-04-30'
```

I need to change the above source table to the two output tables as shown below, covering the entire date range from Apr 1 to Apr 30:

[image]

[image]

Can someone provide me a T-SQL query to develop the two output tables using the Source table?

There is a limitation in my report application, I **cannot** use any database object such as temp tables (#), table variables (@), CTE (WITH), etc.

I need a purely ad-hoc query, developing only derived tables as shown below:

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT ...
     FROM tableX
     INNER JOIN tableY ON ...
     ) DerivedTable
```

I need all data manipulation to be done within the 'DerivedTable', **without** using any database objects.

If you can provide me a solution to develop even one of the two tables, it would be great.

Comment: Normally I'd approach this by standing up a new permanent table in the database to serve as a calendar table, that would be in-scope for the sort of reporting constraints you're facing. Would creating a calendar table in the database be an option here?

Comment: Agreed, having a *calendar* table available in the database, or a utility database, makes these sorts of reporting requirements both much easier and more performant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to the second result set.

Similar approach to @David Browne - Microsoft, used a different approach to "make" a date table

> Create the sample data, shown in the question

```
create table src (
     id char(3)
    ,name char(3)
    ,value int
    ,startDate date
    ,endDate date
)
go
insert into src values 
('abc','xyz',250,'20210410','20210415')
,('abc','xyz',150,'20210424','20210430')
```

> Description: I created 2 derived tables a, b which have matching dates to the "date" table, and all dates, respectively. This was needed in order to get all the dates to show up in the final result set. Getting the "value" from the matching table allows for you to get the values for those dates in which we have a value. The 4th field, date, can really be obtained from either derived table

> Query:

```
DECLARE @RangeStart AS date = '2021-04-01';
DECLARE @RangeEnd AS date = '2021-04-30';

select 
     b.id
    ,b.name
    ,a.value
    ,a.date
from 
(
SELECT
        id
        ,name
        ,value
        ,DateTable.Date
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @RangeStart, @RangeEnd) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @RangeStart)
    FROM    sys.objects a
    )DateTable 
    left outer join src
    ON DateTable.Date between src.startdate and src.enddate
) a

inner join (
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @RangeStart, @RangeEnd) + 1)
        id
        ,name
        ,NULL as value 
        ,DateTable.Date
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @RangeStart, @RangeEnd) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @RangeStart)
    FROM    sys.objects a
    )DateTable 
    inner join src ON 1=1
    )b on a.date = b.date
```

**UPDATE 8/11/2021**: Modified to account for multiple `ID`'s
What Changed:

- The second nested query (which brings back all dates with no values) was modified to have a `DISTINCT` instead of a `TOP`, as the old way would cap it at 30 records. Without the `TOP` you'd have a Cartesian Product, hence the `DISTINCT` clause which brings back one record per day/id.
- The join between the two derived tables was changed from `INNER` to a `RIGHT` join, as the inner would only bring dates where there was *no* record in the left table (only one, even if multiple ID's need it), though we want to bring back all of them
- The outermost query changed to have the DATE field come from the "right" table instead.
- The join between the two derived tables now joins on both the date and the ID, as we'd otherwise get a Cartesian Product

**QUERY**:

```
DECLARE @RangeStart AS date = '2021-04-01';
DECLARE @RangeEnd AS date = '2021-04-30';

SELECT 
     b.id
    ,b.name
    ,a.value
    ,b.[date]
FROM 
(
SELECT
         id
        ,name
        ,value
        ,DateTable.[Date]
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @RangeStart, @RangeEnd) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @RangeStart)
    FROM    sys.objects a
    )DateTable 
    left outer join src
    ON DateTable.Date between src.startdate and src.enddate
) a

RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
         id
        ,name
        ,NULL as value 
        ,DateTable.Date
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @RangeStart, @RangeEnd) + 1)
            Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, @RangeStart)
    FROM    sys.objects a
    )DateTable 
    INNER JOIN src ON 1=1
    )
    b ON a.[date] = b.[date] 
    AND a.id = b.id
ORDER BY 1,4;
```

Comment: thanks, i roughly tried it works; tomorrow I will make a fair copy, and get back; appreciate your help

Comment: in my actual data set there are many employees, I have shown only one employee with ID = ABC, and Name = XYZ.    The ID column is a unique identifier for an employee.  Also I have some other employees where there is no break in the date range from Start Date to End Date. For example, an Employee PQR has the range: Apr 1 to Apr 10, and Apr 11 to Apr 30. Hence there is no break in range; another employee RST has the date range Apr 1 to Apr 30. What adjustments do I need to make the above query suit my requirement ?

Comment: please see my post with slight modification. Can you let me know what changes I need to make in the query you provided me yesterday ?

Comment: i applied the new code; say there is a break in the range for an ID, Apr 1-18, Apr 19-28, but no value from Apr 29-Apr 30. The last two days are missing in my final output.

Comment: i mean the first range is Apr 1-18, with data, the second range is Apr 19-28 with data; there is no  data for Apr 29 or 30.

Comment: i have added one more ID for a person with ID   = HDF; for HDF, your new solution misses the data from Apr 20 to Apr 30

Comment: your solution when i tried now roughly, it works. I will try with actual data, which has around 6-7 column, not just the the two (id, name) I have mentioned here.

Comment: your solution has worked in my actual dataset, with about 5 columns; i have two other large datasets to complete; if/once successful, I will mark your answer.

Comment: One of the two datasets I have mentioned here has multiple columns - Value1,Value2,...., apart from ID1,ID2,Name1,Name2..

Comment: your solution has worked in all my actual datasets; thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
drop table if exists #src;
go
create table #src(
     id char(3)
    ,name char(3)
    ,value int
    ,startDate date
    ,endDate date);

insert into #src values 
('abc','xyz',250,'20210410','20210415')
,('abc','xyz',150,'20210424','20210430');

declare 
  @RangeStart AS date = '2021-04-01',
  @RangeEnd AS date = '2021-04-30';

with
l as (select 1 n from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) as v(n)),
range_cte as (
    select top (datediff(day, @RangeStart, @RangeEnd)+1) 
           dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select null))-1, @RangeStart) dt
    from l l1, l l2,l l3, l l4) /* 8^4 sequence n */ 
select s.id, s.name, s.startDate, s.endDate, r.dt,
       case when r.dt>=s.startDate and r.dt<=s.endDate then s.value
            else null end calc_val
from range_cte r
     cross join #src s 
order by s.id, s.name, s.startDate, s.endDate, r.dt;
```

[edit] without CTE

```
declare 
  @RangeStart AS date = '2021-04-01',
  @RangeEnd AS date = '2021-04-30';

select s.id, s.name, s.startDate, s.endDate, r.dt,
       case when r.dt>=s.startDate and r.dt<=s.endDate then s.value
            else null end calc_val
from (
    select top (datediff(day, @RangeStart, @RangeEnd)+1) 
           dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select null))-1, @RangeStart) dt
    from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) l1(n),
         (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) l2(n),
         (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) l3(n),
         (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) l4(n)) r
     cross join #src s 
order by s.id, s.name, s.startDate, s.endDate, r.dt;
```

Comment: Although the right tool for the job, CTE's are not an option as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @SteveC    I do not understand the SELECT 1 n FROM (values(1),....).   You have this 4 times, and each of the 4 lines has eight 1s.   How should I use this logic ? Do the 4 lines means the 4 output columns - ID, Name, Value, Date ?

Comment: @user3812887 those 4 subqueries are used to generate a sequence of up to 4,096 rows (8^4=5096) to expand the range into individual days.  The 4 queries are CROSS JOIN'ed however the TOP clause of the SELECT statement constrains the expansion to only what's needed.  The explanation that worked for me was from [Jeff Moden](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1)

Comment: Took another look at it was possible to simplify the query a little

Comment: @steveC    you are using CTE here

Comment: @user3812887 Please review again

Comment: @SteveC    thanks i will fully try your solution tomorrow. I generally do not use this sequence of 4096.. stuff, that is the reason why i was hesitant; but will try tomorrow; also , in my actual scenario, there are a lot more dimension columns (I have mentioned only ID and Name here, for simplifying the issue). Should I generate more sequences if there are 6 columns instead of just the two I have mentioned here (ID and Name) ?

Comment: @SteveC    I tired your query now; I see a small issue; for example for a date range of Apr 10- Apr 15 for id =  'abc', I see the entire set of 30 days (Apr 1-Apr 30) under the column called    -  dt  . It should only be 6 rows, not 30.  I think this is because of the CROSS JOIN. Can you slightly alter the code?  Also, remember that the table can have more persons, not just the ID 'abc';  please see my updated post

Comment: @user3812887 when I set the RangeStart to '2021-04-10' and RangeEnd to '2021-04-15' the query generates 6 rows per input row from the source table.  It's correct, no?  To add more columns from the source you could add them to the select list.  No need to generate more sequences.

Comment: @SteveC    the RangeStart and RangeEnd parameters are almost always the 1st and last days of the month.  -  Apr 1 and Apr 30;    you can see the additional information i have posted in my original post

Comment: @stevec  currently i am getting 30 rows for each of the two ranges (Apr 10-15; Apr 24-30) for 'abc'     total  60 rows;   will get back again;   i sincerely thank you for you help; appreciate it.

Comment: @stevec   i do not see a range between Apr 1-9 or Apr 16-23

Comment: @user3812887 there are two different ranges.  The range which governs how many rows are generated uses the declared variables.  The range which overlaps onto that is taken from the source table.  The date range in the source table doesn't impact what range is calculated.

Comment: @stevec SELECT id, name, dt, calc_val
FROM [YourResultSet]
WHERE dt = '2021-04-10';    for this query I get two rows for '2021-04-10; one with a calc_val 250, the other with calc_val NULL. Can the row with NULL for calc_val column be removed ?

Comment: @stevec      On the other hand, SELECT id, name, dt, calc_val FROM [YourResultSet] WHERE dt = '2021-04-01';  i see two rows with both having NULL for calc_val column. I need only one row with NULL, since for Apr 1, the value is NULL

Comment: @stevec     Can you produce a result set that is similar to my 'Output table desired (2)'  ?Thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: @user3812887 when I set the declared variable range from '2021-04-01' to '2021-04-30' and enter your data (from picture) into the source table (#src in my answer) it produces the correct results.

Comment: @SteveC   Hello Steve,  thanks very much for all your help and effort; for now I went with the other solution, but have learned a good deal from your suggestion; thanks for your time.

Comment: @user3812887 if you were to delete your other question you would get those downvoted points back.  Hit the +1 button here too please

Comment: @SteveC   I have deleted my other post; please undo the penalty given; and thanks very much for your help; how to do the   +1 ?

Comment: @user3812887 there's no penalty I can undo because I almost never downvote and did not downvote you.  To give a +1 click the upward pointing chevron next to the answer.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Start with something like this to generate a sequence table as large as you need.

```
DECLARE @RangeStart AS date = '2021-04-01'
DECLARE @RangeEnd AS date = '2021-04-30'


select dateadd(day,q.i, @RangeStart)
from (select row_number() over (order by (select null))-1 i 
      from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) v1(i),
           (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) v2(i)
      ) q
where q.i <= datediff(day,@rangeStart,@RangeEnd)
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, i think am coming close